# $f:X \rightarrow D$ is constant for connected $X$ and $D=\{0,1\}$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I am trying to understand the following theorem

> Let $D$ denote the two point discrete space $\{0,1\}$, $X$ is connected if and only if for any continuous map $X \rightarrow D$ is constant function.

I am okay with $\Leftarrow$ direction but having a problem understanding $\Rightarrow$. In my notes, I wrote

> $(\Rightarrow )$ Since $f$ is continuous and $X$ is connected, $f(X)$ is connected in $D$. And since $D$ is discrete, $f$ is a constant map.

I don't understand why the last part holds. i.e., why discrete set $D$ implies $f$ is a constant map.

The function $f: X \to \{ 0,1 \}$ can be $ f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 &&   \\ 1 &&  \end{cases}$ depending on the situations and I guess connectedness is crucial to show $f$ is constant, but cannot remember why.

Comment: The connected subspaces of any discrete space are just the singletons. So $f(X)$ is a singleton, and thus $f$ is constant.

Comment: I guess I should add that the empty set also counts as a connected subspace, but then $f$ is the empty function, which is still constant since $D\not=\varnothing$ (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1949584/is-the-empty-function-constant) but this is getting degenerate and pedantic. You can avoid this mess by imposing that $X$ be nonempty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To further expand on the comment,  if $f(D)$ is non-constant,  then $f(D)=\{0,1\}$, which is disconnected since it can be written as the union of the open sets $\{0\}\cup \{1\}$, this contradicts $f(D)$ being connected, thus $f$ is constant.